# How to get the content of the rows above and below my selected row in list view?

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I am getting an error intermittently with my listview when I click on a row in order to delete its contents and merge the contents of the above and below rows into one row.  when I use the code in another part of the program it works but for some reason it gives an error here in the code I list below.  Is there a way to get the code from the above and below rows of my selected row in listview?

```
             if ( iIndex > 0 && iIndex +1 < listView1.Items.Count)
            {///get my error on the row below for content one 'InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.'
                string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[-1]].SubItems[0].Text;
                string content2 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[1]].SubItems[0].Text;
                string NumCellAbove = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0] - 1].SubItems[1].Text;
                string NumCellBelow = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0] + 1].SubItems[1].Text;
                int TotalFsCt1 = int.Parse(content);
                int TotalFsCtAbove1 = int.Parse(NumCellAbove);
                int TotalFsCtBelow1 = int.Parse(NumCellBelow);
                int TotalFsCt= TotalFsCt1 + TotalFsCtAbove1 + TotalFsCtBelow1;
                int TotalFsCtAbove = TotalFsCt1 + TotalFsCtAbove1;
                int TotalFsCtBelow = TotalFsCt1 + TotalFsCtBelow1;
                if (content1 != "Free Space" && content2 != "Free Space")
                {
                    listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.FocusedItem);
                    ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Free Space");
                    item3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    item3.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                    item3.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item3,
                    content, Color.Black, Color.Yellow, item3.Font));
                    item3.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item3,
                    "        0", Color.Black, Color.White, item3.Font));
                    listView1.Items.Insert(iIndex, item3);
                    totalMBct1 += newTotalct;
                    SetHeight(listView1, 256 / listView1.Items.Count);
                    if (button1.Enabled == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enabling button again memory less then full!");
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
       }


    ////Yet this code below this line works fine and never gives the error
                if (iIndex > 0 && iIndex < listView1.Items.Count)
            {
                string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].SubItems[0].Text;
                string content2 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0] - 1].SubItems[0].Text;
                string NumCellAbove = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0] -1].SubItems[1].Text;
                int TotalFsCt1 = int.Parse(content);
                int TotalFsCtAbove1 = int.Parse(NumCellAbove);
                int TotalFsCtAbove = TotalFsCt1 + TotalFsCtAbove1;
                if (content1 != "Free Space" && content2 == "Free Space")
                {
                    string Above = TotalFsCtAbove.ToString();
                    listView1.Items[iIndex -1].Remove();
                    listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.FocusedItem);
                    ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Free Space");
                    item3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    item3.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                    item3.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item3,
                    Above, Color.Black, Color.Yellow, item3.Font));
                    item3.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item3,
                    "        0", Color.Black, Color.White, item3.Font));
                    listView1.Items.Insert(iIndex-1, item3);
                    totalMBct1 += newTotalct;
                    SetHeight(listView1, 256 / listView1.Items.Count);
                    if (button1.Enabled == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enabling button again memory less then full!");
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: As mentioned Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index' is the culprit. The index starts at 0. Hence the error.

Comment: I get that but what I cant understand is why it works in the second section of code and how do I get the row above my selected row?

Comment: i just need to be able to click a row in my listview and save the contents of the above and below rows if the words "Free space" are in them and then delete the above and below rows and merge them into one row.

Comment: Make string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[-1]].SubItems[0].Text; as string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].SubItems[0].Text;

Comment: but that only selects the row i am clicking on. what about the row above? Are you saying it works in the other code because i have string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].SubItems[0].Te‌​xt stored first before i use content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[-1]].SubItems[0].T‌​ext;?

Comment: rows above will all the rows whose indicies are less than the selected index right? i.e. if n is your selected index then o to n-1 will be index of the rows above and n + 1 to N will be index of rows below selected row.

Comment: You are using two approaches `listView1.SelectedIndices[-1]` and `listView1.SelectedIndices[0] - 1` why don't you use the same at both the places. It is not C# issue or .net issue its the logic issue. This soution was suggested by me in one of your earlier questions but you didn't think of using it all similar places. You don't event notice the code difference between the second block and first block.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the element at the position -1 from your `SelectedIndices`, because there is no item at the position -1, so you get an exception. What you probably wanted to do is to get the item at the position of the selectedIndex - 1. Therefore you'd have to do something like that:

```
string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]-1].SubItems[0].Text;
string content2 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]+1].SubItems[0].Text;
```

However, I'd suggest to firstly check wether an item is actually selected:

```
if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
    return;
```

And you should check wether your list contains enough elements:

```
if (listView1.Items.Count == 0 || listView2.Items.Count < 2)
    return;
```

I don't quite understand though why you used a correct attempt in the second example, which worked, but not in the first one.

Comment: well I know that caused some confusion but it didn't matter weather I used    either one really [0]-1 or [-1] for the top it gave the error either way.  Maybe what you are saying about if   if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count() == 0)
return; will work I will try it.

Comment: if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count() == 0)  does not work it gives an error it says I am missing a directive or assembly language for the .Count()

Comment: So I rewrote the code and I figured out the cause but I don't know how to fix it. what appears to be happening is when you use the [0]-1 for the above row and the [0]+1 for the below row in the same. if statement {} it seems to give the error. If I put them in separate if statements it works. The problem with this is that I need to get the above and below rows in order to get my code to work so I need to use [0]-1 and [0]+1 together.

Comment: There must be some kind of work around for this and reason why its happening?

Comment: @Lecy277 I don't quite understand your problem. If it is another one as the title says, you should however ask a new question.

Comment: Let me ask you this question then. on my third column I had a header called allocation bit and in the subitems it has either a string of "        0"  which is designated to mean "free space or a string of "        1" for "allocated.  when I do an if statement of if (contentSelect == "        1" && contentBelow == "        0") can c# tell the difference between the two strings with all the spaces in front of the 1 and the 0?

Comment: @Lecy277 with different amount of spaces you'll get always false returned by an equality comparison. However, you could use trim to avoid that problem. But actually I meant with asking a new question, creating a new post.

Comment: I finally figured it out So the issue is that the index if you  clicked on the first item in your listview which is index 0 will attempt to read both -1 & 1 even if those strings are not called in a function but are used as I had them to store my string string content1 = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]-1].SubItems[0].Text; etc. So the work around is to use if statement with the index that you will be selecting which has that string available above or below it.  So if the item clicked on is the second items its means index 1 &if there are only two items only [0]-1 can be used.